# Filter text from a RSS description element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm making a simple rss feed reader via visual studio. I´m using a gridview that loads the title and description elements from each item from the feed(I'm still starting this so I will load the other elements later). To get the information I want from the xml file I'm using the following transformation:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="channel">
        <feedinfo>
          <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <title> 
                <xsl:attribute name="title">
                  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="description">
                  <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </title>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </feedinfo>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is getting the information I want but there is a little problem with the description: it also copies the img part within the description.

Example: Obra do ex-ministro da Economia promete explicar "que interesses e lóbis teve de enfrentar" durante a sua passagem pelo executivo. http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/PublicoRSS/~4/RJMEyUlkY0w" height="1" width="1"

How can i filter this part of the description out?

In the rss feed the description element is like this:

```html
<description>Obra do ex-ministro da Economia promete explicar "que interesses e lóbis teve de enfrentar" durante a sua passagem pelo executivo.<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/PublicoRSS/~4/RJMEyUlkY0w" height="1" width="1"/>;</description>
```

EDIT:

Here's a part of the input:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="/~d/styles/rss2full.xsl"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~d/styles/itemcontent.css"?><rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Publico.pt - Geral</title>
    <link>http://www.publico.pt</link>
    <description>Descrição</description>
    <copyright>© 2014 PÚBLICO Comunicação Social SA</copyright>
    <language>pt-pt</language>
    <lastBuildDate>Thu, 13 Nov 2014 18:11:30 GMT</lastBuildDate>
    <category>Geral</category>
    <ttl>5</ttl>
    <managingEditor>ultimahora@publico.pt (Última Hora)</managingEditor>
    <webMaster>webmaster@publico.pt (Webmaster)</webMaster>
    <image>
      <url>http://static.publico.pt/files/header/img/publico.png</url>
      <title>Publico.pt - Escolha do Editor</title>
      <link>http://www.publico.pt</link>
      <width>85</width>
    </image>
    <item>
      <title>EUA acusam Rússia de "alimentar conflito" na Ucrânia na 26.º reunião do Conselho de Segurança</title>
      <description>Reunião de emergência convocada pelos Estados Unidos serviu apenas para nova troca de acusações. Veículo que serve para transportar militares russos mortos em combate foi avistado a entrar na Ucrânia, diz a OSCE.&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/PublicoRSS/~4/0yBAvZhqVpI" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
      <link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/PublicoRSS/~3/0yBAvZhqVpI/eua-acusam-russia-de-alimentar-conflito-na-ucrania-na-26-reuniao-do-conselho-de-seguranca-1676173</link>
      <category>Mundo</category>
      <pubDate>Thu, 13 Nov 2014 18:07:14 GMT</pubDate>
      <dc:creator>Alexandre Martins</dc:creator>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.publico.pt/mundo/noticia/eua-acusam-russia-de-alimentar-conflito-na-ucrania-na-26-reuniao-do-conselho-de-seguranca-1676173</guid>
    <feedburner:origLink>http://www.publico.pt/mundo/noticia/eua-acusam-russia-de-alimentar-conflito-na-ucrania-na-26-reuniao-do-conselho-de-seguranca-1676173</feedburner:origLink></item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing us the source XML or the part of your XSLT that handles the `description` element. So it is difficult to give you an exact code matching your context. If you do something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="description"/>
```

you should get back only the text nodes descendants of `description`.

---

### Edit:

There is a **VERY BIG** difference between:

```
<description>Obra do ex-ministro da Economia promete explicar "que interesses e lóbis teve de enfrentar" durante a sua passagem pelo executivo.<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/PublicoRSS/~4/RJMEyUlkY0w" height="1" width="1"/>;</description>
```

and:

```
<description>Reunião de emergência convocada pelos Estados Unidos serviu apenas para nova troca de acusações. Veículo que serve para transportar militares russos mortos em combate foi avistado a entrar na Ucrânia, diz a OSCE.&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/PublicoRSS/~4/0yBAvZhqVpI" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
```

In the first example, `<img>` is a separate node within the  element. In the second example, the image is an integral part of the text content of `<description>`. There is no XPath expression that can address the text separately from the image part, or vice versa. You need to resort to parsing the text using string functions. If you can assume that the entire text is before the image part (or any other escaped nested element), you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(description, '&lt;')"/>
```

to get it. Otherwise you'd need to use a recursive named template to "bypass" all such escaped elements nested in the text.

Comment: I'm sorry, by mistake i copied the wrong xslt. I've put the correct one now! As you can see I'm using the command that you are suggesting. I get the description text but I also get the img part that is next to the text. I would like to know how to exclude the img part.

Comment: @JoãoMinhósRodrigues Please add a minimal, but complete example of your input so that we can see if the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I've put a part of the input above. Is it enough for you?

Comment: For reasons I don't  understand, when I paste the code into this page it changes the "<" into "&lt;" in the first case i've put, i've corrected it but when i've put the whole code that you asked me i forgot to correct that error. The point is that the first version of the description that i've put is the real one, so the img is a separate node within the element according to what you explained to me. What should I do in this case?

Comment: In such case my first answer stands: the <img> node will NOT be included in the result of `<xsl:value-of select="description"/>`.

Comment: I used that command and the result was the one that i mencioned. Either way i used your second answer using the '.' as the stop point and is working! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoãoMinhósRodrigues I don't see how what you describe is possible. -- Note: if you extract the substring before `"."`, you will only get the first sentence of the description. I wouldn't call that "working".